# How to get nested element using jSoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to access the nest class `gwt-HTML` from http://folkets-lexikon.csc.kth.se/folkets/#lookup&dricker&0, which contains the following text:

> Böjningar: drack, druckit, drick, dricka, dricker

Some quick, relevant information about the above site: it is an English-Swedish dictionary, where I all I need to do it just slightly modifiy the URL each time and then grab the text that follows after the word **Böjningar**, in this case I would get 'drack, druckit, drick, dricka, dricker'

Here is what I have tried so far

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://folkets-lexikon.csc.kth.se/folkets/#lookup&dricker&0").get();
Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("gwt-HTML");
if(!elements.isEmpty()){
    for(Element element: elements){
        System.out.println(element.data());
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("***********NO RESULTS !!!");
}
```

With the above code, I keep entering the else statement, even though when I inspect the elements of the site, I can see

```
<div class="gwt-HTML">Böjningar: drack, druckit, drick, dricka, dricker</div>
```

How can I gain access to this element?

Here is a screenshot of the data
[image]

Comment: Can you post the error message you got?

Comment: I'm not really getting an error, it's just entering the else statement, indicating that there were no elements found.

Answer (score 0):

Use `select("div.gwt-HTML")` instead of `getElementsByClass("gwt-HTML")`

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://folkets-lexikon.csc.kth.se/folkets/#lookup&dricker&0").get();
Elements elements = document.select("div.gwt-HTML");
if(!elements.isEmpty()){
    for(Element element: elements){
        System.out.println(element.data());
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("***********NO RESULTS !!!");
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it's just entering the ELSE statement, instead of the IF.

Comment: There is no class with name "gwt-HTML" in your HTML DOM at http://folkets-lexikon.csc.kth.se/folkets/#lookup&dricker&0

Comment: When I expand the first item, I can see the the data, and from that when I right click and select 'inspect', I can see the element.

Comment: True but that element is loaded by Ajax. The original DOM gotten by Jsoup on the URL has not "gwt-HTML" class

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense then. How can I still use jSoup to get newly loaded data or must I use something else?

Comment: That will be a big challenge because Jsoup only load your original DOM. A solution will be to code the Translator application not to load by Ajax.